# How to use the "Good" template from Bootstrap in a new Next.js app?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, next.js

I want to use a specific template called "Good" from Bootstrap in my Next.js app.

https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=98871

Shall I just put css here: https://preview.keenthemes.com/good/assets/css/style.bundle.css into my Next.js app?

Or is it any Bootstrap proposed solution to this?